# How would I remake a Batch File into a Shell Script

Tags: java, shell, batch-file

I'm using Sublime Text 2, and I want to be able to compile and run Java Files with one button.

When running Windows, the Batch file Required is:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd %~dp1
javac %~nx1
java %~n1
```

I'm wondering what that would look like in a Shell Script, cause I don't know much about Shell Scripts...

I'm using the Open JDK and JRE in case it matters.

Thanks for the help,

Kelan

Answer (score 3):

The bash equivalent to that script would be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$1")"
javac "$(basename "$1")"
java "$(basename "$1" ".${1##*.}")"
```

Answer (score 0):

A shell script would STILL require running a batch file to start it.   For example, you could write a Ant task that could do what you are asking,  or perhaps a Beanshell script.   But, you still wont be able to avoid making a batch file that launches it.   The batch file that you are using now is as close as you'll get to a single click solution.    Not even a PowerShell script would give you better convenience.

Comment: Will Sublime be able to run a batch file in Ubuntu?